# SKLearn - Understanding Discrepancy Between LogisticRegressionCV classification_report and scores_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I'm running into a weird situation where my sklearn `LogisticRegressionCV` model is apparently getting 100% accuracy (the lack of shuffling is intentional). However, when I ask the model to report its accuracy scores, the accuracy scores per inverse regularization are much lower than 100%. What am I doing wrong?

The model:

```
    
    decoder = LogisticRegressionCV(
        penalty='l1',                       # want sparse parameters
        cv=KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=False),
        Cs=np.logspace(-1, 2, 3),
        random_state=0,                     # reproducibility
        dual=False,                         # Prefer dual=False when n_samples > n_features.
        solver='liblinear',                 # for l1 penalty, must use liblinear or saga
        max_iter=1e5,                       # give plenty of time to get good performance
        fit_intercept=False,
        class_weight='balanced',
    ).fit(X, y)
    
    y_hat = decoder.predict(X)
    
    y_hat_probs = decoder.predict_proba(X)
    
    print(classification_report(y, y_hat))
    print(confusion_matrix(y, y_hat))
```

outputs

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       1.00      1.00      1.00       374
         1.0       1.00      1.00      1.00       105

    accuracy                           1.00       479
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       479
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       479

[[374   0]
 [  0 105]]
```

Asking for `decoder.scores_` yields values nowhere near 100%:

```
{1.0: array([[0.35416667, 0.60416667, 0.61458333],
        [0.64583333, 0.64583333, 0.65625   ],
        [0.59375   , 0.65625   , 0.64583333],
        [0.54166667, 0.57291667, 0.59375   ],
        [0.17894737, 0.61052632, 0.65263158]])}
```

Why is there this discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

`decoder.scores_` are obtained during cross-validation, meaning that they are computed from the data that were not used during the training (1 fold of data is always left for validation).

`y_hat = decoder.predict(X)` - You are computing the metrics on the training set here. Model has seen all of this data during the training, therefore it has easier time to make correct predictions compared to the CV case.

You don't want to evaluate your model on the training set because the outcome of such evaluation can be overly optimistic.

Having big difference between prediction accuracy on the training set compared to validation set usually means that the model is overfitting the data - instead of learning useful representations, it just memorizes the input/output mapping.